# Can we redefine a regex?

Tags: c++, regex, c++14

I am using regex to format my input string, my problem is that my string has to replace too many different values so that I have to use many regexes.

My question is, can I redefine a regex to save the system memory?

```
std::regex y_re("y+");
y_re("a+"); // can I do this, it shows error but is there a way to reuse regex?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try redefining in this way:

```cpp
std::regex y_re("y+");
y_re = std::regex("a+");
```

The memory should be reused.